# Installing oci8 php extension

Tags: centos, php

On a CentOS 7 server, I have installed PHP from remi repository. I need to connect to Oracle 9.2 on a remote machine. Installing oci8 via `yum install oci8` results `OCI8 Version  2.1.0` which is not compatible with Oracle 9.2. The following is from the `phpinfo` output.

```
OCI8 Support    enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support enabled
OCI8 Version    2.1.0
Revision    $Id: 8e84657b6fdeaa913819689ef327ad2808110ed4 $
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version  12.1.0.2.0
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version  12.1
```

Trying to install an earlier version using `pecl install oci8-1.4.10` fails as well:

```
In file included from /var/tmp/oci8/oci8.c:58:0:
/var/tmp/oci8/php_oci8_int.h:56:17: fatal error: oci.h: No such file or directory
 #include <oci.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [oci8.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

What should I do to install oci8 version 1.*?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried these steps yet?:

> Install both RPM packages :

```
rpm -ivh instantclient-basic-linux.XXX.rpm
rpm -ivh instantclient-sdk-linux.XXX.rpm
```

> Install some prerequisite

```
yum install php-pear yum install php-devel
```

> Download the OCI8 extension

```
pear download pecl/oci8 
tar xvzf oci8-1.4.7.tgz 
cd oci8-1.4.7/phpize
```

> Configure the extension with your Oracle client library path (change
>   the path …/11.2/… with your own version) :

```
./configure --with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/
```

> Compile and install

```
make 
make install
```

> Configure SELinux : allows httpd to execute programs that require
>   memory addresses that are both executable and writeable

```
setsebool -P httpd_execmem 1
```

> Add the folowing configuration at the end of php.ini

```
vi /etc/php.ini
[OCI8] extension=oci8.so
```

> Restart Apache

```
service httpd restart
```

> 

Source: http://antoine.hordez.fr/2012/09/30/howto-install-oracle-oci8-on-rhel-centos-fedora/